# How to make String.Split() work on the new line?

Tags: c#

```
string candidates;
string[] candidatesSplit = { };
string line;
int countLines = 0;

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("..\\..\\..\\candidates.txt"); // Read candidates from file

candidates = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();

candidatesSplit = candidates.Split(','); // Split the file with ','

Console.WriteLine(candidatesSplit[30]);
```

Using this code, I wanted to split every ',' and get specific words out from my text file.

My candidates file looks like this:

```
100,Esra Tarak,90,D1,D4,D2,A,B,D,C, ,C,A,D,B,C,D,B,A, ,B,A,C,D,C,D,A,D,B,C,D
101,Cem Ak,84,D1,D5, ,A,C,D,C,C,C,A,C,B,C,D,B,A,C,B,A,C,D,C,C,A,D,B,C,D
```

Code works perfectly for the first line in candidates.txt, however when it comes to the second line on the text file, the output comes out like this:

```
D
101
```

I need it to show only like this

```
101
```

I cannot put a ',' at the end of my lines. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You could use a regular expression to split on newlines and commas

Comment: Or just read line by line and split as you go

Answer (score 1):

Just `Split(Environment.NewLine)` on the entire input first and then `Split(',')` again on each line.

```cs
using var sr = new StreamReader("..\\..\\..\\candidates.txt");
var candidates = sr.ReadToEnd();

foreach (var line in candidates.Split(Environment.NewLine))
{
    var candidatesSplit = line.Split(',');
    Console.WriteLine(candidatesSplit[30]);
}
```